# Nested column-wise cell merging using multicolumn in a long table environment

Tags: tables, multicolumn

The following table is set up as can be seen below. I would like to combine duplicated values in column 1-3 by merging the table cells column-wise. However, as you can see the merging of cells is on a different level or **spans a different number of cells in each considered column**.

```
    \begin{longtable}[!htbp]{ |m{2cm} m{3.7cm} m{2cm} | m{1.8cm} m{1.8cm} m{1.8cm}| }
 \hline
 \textbf{Rating-level} & \textbf{Rating category} & \textbf{Credit risk} & \textbf{Fitch \newline (original)} & \textbf{S\&P \newline (original)} & \textbf{Moody's \newline (original)} \\
 \hline
    \rowcolor{YellowGreen}IG & Highest-grade & Lowest & AAA & AAA & Aaa \\
    \rowcolor{YellowGreen}IG & High grade & Very low & AA+ & AA+ & Aa1 \\
    \rowcolor{YellowGreen}IG & High grade & Very low & AA & AA & Aa2 \\
    \rowcolor{YellowGreen}IG & High grade & Very low & AA- & AA- & Aa3 \\
    \rowcolor{YellowGreen}IG & Upper medium grade & Low & A+ & A+ & A1 \\
    \rowcolor{YellowGreen}IG & Upper medium grade & Low & A & A & A2 \\
    \rowcolor{YellowGreen}IG & Upper medium grade & Low & A- & A- & A3 \\
    \rowcolor{YellowGreen}IG & Medium grade & Moderate & BBB+ & BBB+ & Baa1 \\
    \rowcolor{YellowGreen}IG & Medium grade & Moderate & BBB & BBB & Baa2 \\
    \rowcolor{YellowGreen}IG & Medium grade & Moderate & BBB- & BBB- & Baa3 \\ 
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & Speculative grade & Substantial & BB+ & BB+ & Ba1 \\
    \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & Speculative grade & Substantial & BB & BB & Ba2 \\
    \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & Speculative grade & Substantial & BB- & BB- & Ba3 \\
    \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & Speculative grade & High & B+ & B+ & B1 \\
    \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & Speculative grade & High & B & B & B2 \\
    \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & Speculative grade & High & B- & B- & B3 \\
    \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & Highly speculative grade & Very high & CCC+ & CCC+ & Caa1 \\
    \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & Highly speculative grade & Very high & CCC & CCC & Caa2 \\
    \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & Highly speculative grade & Very high & CCC- & CCC- & Caa3 \\
    % \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & & & & & & \\
    \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & Highly speculative grade & Likely in or \newline near default & CC & CC & \\ 
    % \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & & & & & & \\
    \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & Highly speculative grade & Likely in or \newline near default & & & Ca \\
    % \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & & & & & & \\
    \rowcolor{Apricot}Non-IG & Highly speculative grade & Likely in or \newline near default & C & C & \\   
    \hline
    \rowcolor{Red}Default & Default & In default & D & D & C \\
 \hline
\caption{Numeric ratings mapping table} 
% needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:4thlongtable}
\end{longtable}
```

I tried hours with stacking the multicolumn command on various levels but none gave me the desired output. To clarify, in *column 1*, I would like to have *3 stacked cells* (IG, Non-IG, Def), in *column 2* accordingly *7 stacked cells* and in *column 3* accordingly *9 cells*. Somehow every method I tried, completely screwed up the table layout, merging row-wise and column-wise.

Would highly appreciate any pointers!

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the docmentclass as well as the relevant packages. Please also add a sketch of the expected output.

Comment: In order to clarify: Do you want all 3 cells that currently contain the text "upper medium grade"  to be merged into a single cell that spans 3 rows, and likewise for all other sets of cells? If that's the case, you should take a look at the `\multirow` command as opposed to `\multicolumn`.

Comment: Currently, your table easily fits onto a single page, but you nevertheless used `longtable`. Do you want to add more rows to your table later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the following is closer to the expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 0.5\tabcolsep}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Numeric ratings mapping table} 
\label{tab:4thlongtable}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{ llllll }[hvlines, %
                                  code-before={%
                                     \rowcolor{YellowGreen}{2-11}
                                     \rowcolor{Apricot}{12-23}
                                     \rowcolor{Red}{24}}]
 \textbf{\Block{1-1}{Rating-\\ level}} & \textbf{\Block{1-1}{Rating\\ category}} & \textbf{\Block{1-1}{Credit risk}} & \textbf{\Block{1-1}{Fitch \\ (original)}} & \textbf{\Block{1-1}{S\&P \\ (original)}} & \textbf{\Block{1-1}{Moody's \\ (original)}} \\
    \Block[l]{10-1}{IG}     & Highest-grade                                & Lowest                                        & AAA  & AAA  & Aaa \\
                            & \Block[l]{3-1}{High grade}                   & \Block[l]{3-1}{Very low}                      & AA+  & AA+  & Aa1 \\
                            &                                              &                                               & AA   & AA   & Aa2 \\
                            &                                              &                                               & AA-  & AA-  & Aa3 \\
                            & \Block[l]{3-1}{Upper medium\\ grade}         & \Block[l]{3-1}{Low}                           & A+   & A+   & A1 \\
                            &                                              &                                               & A    & A    & A2 \\
                            &                                              &                                               & A-   & A-   & A3 \\
                            & \Block[l]{3-1}{Medium grade}                 & \Block[l]{3-1}{Moderate}                      & BBB+ & BBB+ & Baa1 \\
                            &                                              &                                               & BBB  & BBB  & Baa2 \\
                            &                                              &                                               & BBB- & BBB- & Baa3 \\ 
    \Block[l]{12-1}{Non-IG} & \Block[l]{6-1}{Speculative\\ grade}          & \Block[l]{3-1}{Substantial}                   & BB+  & BB+  & Ba1 \\
                            &                                              &                                               & BB   & BB   & Ba2 \\
                            &                                              &                                               & BB-  & BB-  & Ba3 \\
                            &                                              & \Block[l]{3-1}{High}                          & B+   & B+   & B1 \\
                            &                                              &                                               & B    & B    & B2 \\
                            &                                              &                                               & B-   & B-   & B3 \\
                            & \Block[l]{6-1}{Highly \\speculative\\ grade} & \Block[l]{3-1}{Very high}                     & CCC+ & CCC+ & Caa1 \\
                            &                                              &                                               & CCC  & CCC  & Caa2 \\
                            &                                              &                                               & CCC- & CCC- & Caa3 \\
                            &                                              & \Block[l]{3-1}{Likely in\\ or near\\ default} & CC   & CC   & \\ 
                            &                                              &                                               &      &      & Ca \\
                            &                                              &                                               & C    & C    & \\   
    Default                 & Default                                      & In default                                    & D    & D    & C \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What means *closer*? That's **exactly** what  I tried all day yesterday! Spot on! I'll mark the answer as 'accepted' accordingly.

I do appreciate your help tremendously. Take care!

Comment: Looking through the code here, I must admit, I would probably have never arrived at a viable solution. Guess, first I'll have to do my homework and familiarise myself with the package. Thanks again

Comment: One follow-up question though. So far, the proposed code/solution compiles but outputs a table that is no different from the original one. My online-based shareLaTeX file compiles but reports that ```\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 0.5\tabcolsep}``` is unknown for the package. And at the position I place the table in, the ```\end{NiceTabular}```throws an error that reads like ```LaTeX3 Error: The key 'NiceMatrix/Blcok/l' is unknown and being ignored```& ```LaTeX error: Something's wrong -- perhaps a missing \item.``` I searched the code but didn't find any missing ```\```.

Comment: To clarify, I have put the missing packages in my main.tex file in the preamble and some were already loaded. I use the document class ```report ``` though if that matters in this situation. Otherwise I assume all else being equal to your setup. 

Does the chosen compile (i.e. XeLaTeX, etc.) matter in this situation?

Comment: The `cell-space-limits` that I used in `\NiceMatrixOptions` was introduced with version 5.9, so most likely you used an older version of the package to compile your code. (current version is 5.12) Either update your packages, or, if you can't, you could try `cell-space-top-limit = 0.5\tabcolsep, cell-space-bottom-limit = 0.5\tabcolsep` instead. This should work with versions newer than 4.1. The second error message is caused by the optional argument `[l]` of `\Block` being unknown. This argument to control the horizontal alignment was introduced in nicematrix version 5.3.

Comment: I'll give it a try immediately. Thanks. Updating the package is not possible, as I rely on the subscription based access to the online LaTeX editor shareLaTeX from my school

Comment: Removing the optional argument ```[l]``` gets obviously rid of the second error message. Adjusting the ```\NiceMatrixOptions``` cmd to the newly proposed alternatives, compiles just fine but doesn't produce the output that you shared. I will set up a new test document and include just the table there tonight, trying to isolate what might cause this discrepancy. I'll also relay a request to the IT dep. to update to a later pkg version.

Thx

Comment: Instead of trying to adjust the code in order to work with an older version of `nicematrix` can't you just upload the latest version of `nicematrix` as a file in your project and compile the example code as is?

Comment: You're most certainly right, but as a newbie who is just using LaTeX for a roughly a month now, I am not sure how to do that. I donwloaded the package as .zip file from the CTAN network from [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix). I read the readme file and tried the installation manual outlined there, but to no avail...

I'll try again. Maybe it is me, maybe it is that the school's licence doesn't allow updating package versions.

Comment: I'll probably download a suitable LaTeX Editor software and try to extract the ```.sty```style file that is generated upon installation. My hope is that I can easily access this file from my offline installation, bec. apparently I can upload ```.sty``` and ```.cls```
 files from other packages that are available on CTAN. So that should hopefully work

Comment: I found the file I was looking for online on this [repository](http://www.tug.org/texlive//devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/). Hope this is legit as this site was not TLS encrypted. Put the file on the same directory level as the main.tex (main document) file and it compiled just fine. Wonderful pkg and awesome help! 

Learnt a lot already by following your train of thoughts leandriis! Much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't know how to include a picture otherwise, so pls see below what I get with your solution so far. I managed to compile the table in a way that the merging of the cells column-wise looks like in your example, but somehow the column width is out of bounds. I tried manually adjusting them using the initial column types that allow specification of the column width in the table environment (`p{2cm}` and `m{2cm}`, but that didn't work.

After looking hours in the [pkg documentation](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf), I am not any further at a working solution. I would love your feedback on this follow-up question, if you have an idea. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did solve it a similar fashion as to what leandriis proposed. Essentially pulled the ```nicematrix.sty``` file from the public repo and put it in my project directory on the same level as my main file. That solved the issues.

Thanks again!